# Unidentified Lego bags in set 11015 (Around the World)

Tags: set-identification

I’ve found some extra bags in a Lego set (11015). Qr codes are 6201540 and 6172064. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Please be advised that QR codes are irrelevant when it comes to set identification. Take couple of clear pictures of you bags you have and edit your question to include them.

Comment: How have you determined they're extra bags ? Are you sure they're not just a normal part of the set ?

Answer (score 3):

Set [11015 "Around the World"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11015) contains *three* instruction booklets (PDFs available from [this LEGO webpage over here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/kids/sets/classic/around-the-world-c200bbd43e1c71c6ae62a325b3de472e)).

Two of the three booklets show a relation between numbered bag and mini-models:

[image: Bags one through four]

[image: Bags five through seven]

It's possible that OP misplaced or is missing one of the instruction booklets, hence the confusion.

(Though, IMO, being a "classic" set of mostly generic bricks, the fun is forgetting about the instructions).